# How can i tell if a python string variable with an empty string value is using single quotes or double quotes at init time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7, types

Is there any way to tell how an empty string variable was intialized in python? If I initialize a variable with empty double-quotes. Can I later find out that variable was initialized with empty double quotes vs empty single quotes?

```
>>> test_str = ""
>>> type(test_str)
<class 'str'>
>>> test_str = ''
>>> type(test_str)
<class 'str'>
```

Thanks

Comment: No. It’s merely syntax, it has zero influence on the resulting string.

Comment: Nope. And keep in mind that there's also the tripple-single-quote and tripple-double-quote syntax. Again, the result is a string and you cannot find out how it was initially created.

Comment: That information is not stored. You can of cause use a parser to retrieve it from the source code.

Comment: Bear in mind also that string objects can be created other than as a constant in the code. For example `file.readline()`.

Comment: No need to - it is all the same: `print('' == "" == '''''' == """""" == r"" == rf"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The starting quote type merely changes what terminating quote type the parser will look for while parsing the source code. Meaning, if the string starts with `'`, then the parser will look for the next `'` to know when the string ends, and vice versa with `"`. That's all. That information is not relevant to anything else and isn't preserved. There are also a thousand other ways to create a string, e.g.:

```
test_str = '' "" '' "" + '' + ""
```

Same result, an empty string. How would you even preserve this information and to what end?